# How do I find the speed of an ice chunk over an ice rink when a person walks atop?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below shows a person whose mass is $60\,kg$ is standing over a chunk of ice whose mass is $125\,kg$ which was initially at rest. The person runs across the ice chunk with a speed of $3.7\,\frac{m}{s}$ with respect of the ice chunk. What will be the speed of the ice chunk with respect of the ice rink?.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&0.6\,\frac{m}{s}\\
2.&3.6\,\frac{m}{s}\\
3.&24\,\frac{m}{s}\\
4.&1.2\,\frac{m}{s}\\
5.&24\,\frac{m}{s}\\
\end{array}$

I'm stuck with this problem as I'm not sure how to proceed with the appropiate calculation for the speed of the ice chunk. Should I consider that there is a conservation of momentum?. How exactly should I put the equation for the momentum?. Can someone help me with this?. I would really like to show something but in this problem I'm stuck at the very beginning.

I believe that for this problem I have to consider the momentum at the beginning is the same at the end but how can I put these into math?.

Answer (score 1):

Conservation of linear momentum.

Initial momentum is zero.

Let the velocity of the ice chunk relative to the ground be $-v$ (it has to go backwards).

The velocity of the person is $3.7$ m/s relative to the ice chunk, but $3.7-v$ m/s relative to the ground. That is very important.

Write down an expression for the total momentum of person and ice chunk. Set it equal to zero. Solve to find $v$.

*In response to a comment...* If you want to assume that the velocity of the ice chunk is $v$ m/s forwards, then you would have to make the person's velocity be $3.7+v$ m/s. Say total momentum is zero and solve. You will discover that $v$ is a negative value (going in the opposite direction to what you thought).

Comment: Perhaps can you show the equations so I can follow what you meant?. I don't know how to find the total momentum for the person and the ice chunk.

Comment: Momentum of person + momentum of ice chunk = 0

Comment: Do you know how to find the momentum of an object if you know its mass and its velocity?

Comment: I do know $p=mv$ But I'm confused with the relative velocity. Which speed should I use for the momentum of the person and the momentum of the ice chunk?.

Comment: Use $(3.7-v)$ for the person and $-v$ for the ice chunk.

Comment: Okay using this I got $1.2\,\frac{m}{s}$ which I believe it is the answer. But **why** should I assume that the velocity for the ice chunk is going backwards?. Initial momentum **why** is it equal to zero?. Is it because both are at rest?. So when he starts running that will be the final momentum and not the initial?.

Comment: What would happen if I consider that the velocity of the ice chunk is *positive*, will it yield the same result?

Comment: Because the total momentum is zero, one object will be moving forwards (positive momentum) and the other is moving backwards (negative momentum).